# Is joining two tables via a third in linq using properties equivalent to joining all together?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have a bunch of linq queries performed against databases entities in C#, oversimplifying they are of the form:

```
from f in Foo
join v in Var on f.FooVar.vId equals v.Id
```

vs

```
from f in Foo
join fv in FooVar on f.FooVarId equals fv.Id
join v in Var on fv.vId equals v.Id
```

I believe they are equivalent.

Is there any performance or other consideration on choosing either? for example when the FK is of a nullable type?.

P.S. not sure if the title express this accurately

Comment: Look at the SQL generated.  I wouldn't be surprised if they were the same.